# is there a way to find the location of object based on images from drone?

Tags: image-processing, geolocation, object-detection, detection, yolo

I am doing a project, and got a bit stuck and would love some suggestion/guidness.
I have a video from drone, I use a ml model to detect objects in the video from the drone.
I want to know the gps coordinate of that objects.
I have the gps coordinate of the drone, heights, speed and some more info.

would love to some help/suggestions to solve this problem.

Thanks

Tried to calculated it by myself using the angle of the image.